# SQL0968C The file system is full. SQLSTATE=57011 in db2

Tags: database, db2, database-administration, db2-luw

When I am calling a stored procedure in db2 to populate the data into table, it is giving me the below error-

> SQL0968C  The file system is full.  SQLSTATE=57011

Also my C drive space is getting reduced. I am using db2 9.7 on windows machine.

I dint know why it is taking the memory of C drive when I am calling stored procedure and it is taking more than 2 hours to populate the data but somehow after 2 hours i stopped the process and my C drive space get released and data is not updated in the tables as I stopped the process.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Follow this link,I hope help you https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00968c.html

Comment: How is the table populated? Is it one transaction? How are logs configured? How much data is populated? Where is it stored?

Comment: Have you configured any other file locations? Where would you think the data should go?

Comment: @data_henrik. The table is populated with stored procedure and it is one transaction. the size of data is 22000 rows and it is going in c drive by defualt. I mentioned the D drive while installing.

Comment: @govind: any temporary data that is created? You need disk space for transaction logs, for the data itself and for temporary data